# First update lost wireless

Tags: 12.04, wireless, updates

I'm using **ubuntu 12.04 LTS** and I use a DLink wireless adapter to connect to the internet and after my first update and a reboot I lost wireless connect completely and I've looked around and tried **remove bcmwl-kernal-source** but on the terminal it said it couldn't be found so nothing was removed.

How can I get my internet back?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know exactly what model of wifi card you're using, but perhaps *installing* the bcmwl-kernal-source package would solve the issue.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: Brother fixed it I dunno what he did but thanks for your answer